# VideoJS v5 - adding custom components in ES6 - am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, video.js

I'm writing a social sharing plugin for [VideoJS v5](https://github.com/videojs/video.js): I want to add a div to the player markup, below the control bar, which contains a couple links that will allow social sharing of the player instance in an article on my site. I'm working in ES6.

The VideoJS documentation is minimal, especially for v5 - I'm scratching around in the source to try and figure out how to do it. I did find [this example](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/5.0-Change-Details#videojs-50-subclassing-examples) of subclassing VideoJS components.

Here's what I've got so far - apologies if I'm committing stylistic crimes, I've not had much experience with VideoJS plugins or ES6 classes.

```
videojs.plugin('social-share', function(opts) {
  let player = this;

  const Component = videojs.getComponent('Component');
  const ClickableComponent = videojs.getComponent('ClickableComponent');

  class VjsShareBar extends Component {
    constructor(player, opts) {
      super(player, opts);
    }

    createEl() {
      return super.createEl('div', {
        className: 'vjs-share-bar video-share share-buttons'
      }, {
        'role': 'group'
      });
    }
  }

  class VjsShareButton extends Component {
    constructor(player, opts) {
      super(player, opts);
    }

    createEl() {
      return super.createEl('a', {
        className: 'share-button'
      })
    }
  }

  let twitterShareBtn = new VjsShareButton(player, opts);
  twitterShareBtn.addClass('twitter');

  let twitterShareIcon = new Component(player, opts);

  let fbShareBtn = new VjsShareButton(player, opts);
  fbShareBtn.addClass('facebook');

  let vjsShareBar = player.addChild(new VjsShareBar(player, opts));
  vjsShareBar.addChild(twitterShareBtn);
  vjsShareBar.addChild(fbShareBtn);

});
```

This adds the expected elements to the player markup inside the `video-js` container:

```
<div class="vjs-share-bar video-share share-buttons" role="group">
    <a class="share-button twitter"></a>
    <a class="share-button facebook"></a>
</div>
```

Do I need this approach of extending a new subclass for each element? It seems a bit clunky. Is there a way I can simply create a new instance of the VideoJS [Component](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/component.js) class for each element I want to create, passing in a different tagname and classes each time? I need to add spans within the `a` tags, and the idea of extending a new `Component` subclass for each seems overkill.

(Existing event handlers in my site will handle clicks on the links, so I'm not going to listen for click events with the player API. And I'm using the simple `Component` class because don't want the extra bumph more specific classes like `ClickableComponent` and `Button` add to the markup.)

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty old, but I wrote up a post on how to create custom components in a flexible way for Video.js.

Unfortunately their docs aren't super helpful yet, so I wrote this up.
https://nikushx.com/blog/2019/05/21/creating-custom-components-with-video-js/

```
class ToggleCaptionsButton extends videojs.getComponent('Button') {

    constructor(player, options = {}) {
        super(player, options);
            this.addClass('vjs-captions-toggle');

            // captions are "on" by default
            this.addClass('vjs-captions-on');
        }

    /**
    * Toggle the subtitle track on and off upon click
    */
    public handleClick(_e) {
        const textTracks = this.player.textTracks();

        for (let i = 0; i < textTracks.length; i++) {
            if (textTracks[i].kind !== 'subtitles') {
                continue;
            }

            // toggle showing the captions
            if (textTracks[i].mode === 'showing') {
                textTracks[i].mode = 'hidden';
                this.removeClass('vjs-captions-on');
            } else {
                textTracks[i].mode = 'showing';
                this.addClass('vjs-captions-on');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved many people time with your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Nikush great answer I would like to add some information so other people can find solution faster.

You can use the official video-js plugin generator to have deep idea about the bes plugin/component template for video.js. [videojs/generator-videojs-plugin](https://github.com/videojs/generator-videojs-plugin)

After long trip of stuck because of the low documentation quality provided by video.js This is the best template I found for the:

**1. Component:**

```
     import document from "global/document";
     import video.js from "video.js";
     /**
     * @file etom-extras-logo-control-bar.js
     */
    
    /**
     * Add company logo with hyperlink link to control bar with options.
     *
     * @extends Button
     */
    
    //+++  Request videojs component (Button) [OR ANY OTHER COMPONENT LIKE (Component) +++//
    const Button = videojs.getComponent("Button");
    
    //+++  Default options for the Component. +++//
    const defaults = {};
    
    class EtomExtrasLogoInBar extends Button {
      /**
       * Creates an instance of this class.
       *
       * @param {Player} player
       *        The `Player` that this class should be attached to.
       *
       * @param {Object} [options={}]
       *        The key/value store of player options.
       */
    
      constructor(player, options = {}) {
        super(player, options);
        options = videojs.mergeOptions(defaults, options);
    
        const settings = {};
        const {} = settings;

        // start your work!!

      }
    }
    
    videojs.registerComponent("etomExtrasLogoInBar", EtomExtrasLogoInBar);
    export default EtomExtrasLogoInBar;
```

**1. Plugin:**

```
import document from "global/document";
import video.js from "video.js";

/** Import required plugins 
**  import "videojs-playlist";
**  import "./extras/plugins/overlay/etom-extras-videojs-overlay";
* @file etom-extras-playlist-extend.js
*/
/**
* Extend videoJs default playlist with extra features..
*
* @extends Plugin
*/

const Plugin = videojs.getPlugin("plugin");

// Default options for the plugin.
const defaults = {};


class EtomExtras extends Plugin {
  /**
   * Create a EtomExtras plugin instance.
   *
   * @param  {Player} player
   *         A Video.js Player instance.
   *
   * @param  {Object} [options]
   *         An optional options object.
   *
   *         While not a core part of the Video.js plugin architecture, a
   *         second argument of options is a convenient way to accept inputs
   *         from your plugin's caller.
   */

    constructor(player, options = {}) {
       super(player, options);
       options = videojs.mergeOptions(defaults, options);
    
       const settings = {};
       const {} = settings;

       // start your work!!

      }
   }

// Define default values for the plugin's `state` object here.
EtomExtras.defaultState = {};

// Include the version number.
EtomExtras.VERSION = VERSION;
// Register the plugin with video.js.
videojs.registerPlugin("etomExtras", EtomExtras);

export default EtomExtras;
```

Keep in mind you can make the component and the plugin in the same file and use the same as above.

Thank you all.